# swift sqlite3 database inserts text binding in two columns

Tags: ios, swift, database, sqlite

I am new to sqlite3 and have been following several tutorials online.  My issue is, when inspecting the database I have created, using any free gui to inspect it, two of my columns have the same data. I am missing the data from my first column. I have done the following within my viewDidLoad() method:

```
let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
               .appendingPathComponent("RFDevices.sqlite")

if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK {
        print("error opening database")
    }

if sqlite3_exec(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Devices (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, manufacturer TEXT, model TEXT, lowerfreq FLOAT, upperfreq FLOAT)", nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
                let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
                print("error creating table: \(errmsg)")
            }
```

Now this has created the table and the structure, I create a function to add values to the database:

```
func insertSQLEntry(manufacturer:String, model:String, LowerFreq:Float, UpperFreq:Float) {
    //creating a statement
    var stmt: OpaquePointer?

    //the insert query
    let queryString = "INSERT INTO devices (manufacturer, model, lowerfreq, upperfreq) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"

    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, manufacturer, -1, nil)
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, model, -1, nil)
        sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 3, Double(LowerFreq))
        sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 4, Double(UpperFreq))
    }

    if sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("failure inserting hero: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }
}
```

Now to add an entry I will call that function using something like below:

```
insertSQLEntry(manufacturer: "Sennheiser", model: "Range B2", LowerFreq: 654.000, UpperFreq: 678.000)
```

If I inspect the result of above, the manufacturer column has 'Range B2' in it, as does the model column. The last two columns show the correct values. I do not see 'Sennheiser' in my entry. I am assuming that my issue is to do with the fact that for the database, the first column is technically the id column, which is set to autoincrement an integer, so I do not need to specify this in my statement. 
Any suggestions on what I have missed?

Comment: These two tips may not solve your issue.  But No. 1, you are using Float as a data type inside the SQ statement in creating a database.  That's a data type that Swift supports, not that SQLite supports.  Change it REAL.  No. 2, you are force-wrapping a variable in creating a database.  You should not do that.